# How do I impliment a clock/timer in Java?

Tags: java

How do I impliment a clock/timer in Java? I have a program that saves file data in memory for future use. I'd like to add a timer to check the time the file was created and when it has changed. current time - cached time = duration

Comment: That's very broad, and depends a lot on your program, schedule complexity, desired modularity and such. Possible answers range from "use java.util.Timer and java.util.TimerTask" to "use Terracotta Quartz"....

Comment: Thanks for the advice everyone. All of you have given me the insight I was looking for. Im going to try some of the suggestions and ill update the thread once Ive completed the task.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you just want to check the file's metadata and compare it with the systems time. The getLastModifiedTime and setLastModifiedTime method sound like exactly what you need.

You can read about this [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileAttr.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the java.util date and time. For instance:

Date now = new Date(); set's now to the current date

You can save that date as atached to the file and when you want to compare to dates you can use:

long time = (new Date()).getTime() - readDate.getTime(); 
That would give you the time in miliseconds